# Which event do I simulate to get the title to show on a marker for google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm migrating from google maps api v2 to v3.   In v2 we had a custom overlay for the tooltip, which is similar to the title in v3.  I'd like to get rid of the custom overlay, as it's not working right in v3 anyways and would be much simpler to maintain as a title.  The problem is that I have pieces outside the map that display the tooltip when they are interacted with.  I thought that I could get the title to display with something like this:

```
   showTooltip: function(i) {
      var marker = i && this.MARKERS ? this.MARKERS[i] : this.marker;
      if (!marker.infoWindowOpen) {
         google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover', {ltLng: marker.getPosition()});
      }
   }
```

However the title isn't displaying.  The idea was to simulate mousing over the marker so that the title would be displayed.

Comment: The title is a simple HTML-tooltip, there is no programmatically way to show it.

Comment: Ended up not needing this, so I didn't take the time to try the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how i made a toggle to turn the captions on and off, i think you can use the same methodology:

```
body .gmnoprint[title] { 
    overflow: visible !important; 
    width: auto  !important; 
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1  !important; 
}


body[data-captions='true'] .gmnoprint[title*="^"]:after {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    content: attr(title);
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    left: 0em;
    padding: 0em 0.6em;
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    white-space: pre;
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 3px #fff;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

then you can just toggle the body tag data-captions attrib to turn the captions on and off.

it uses CSS to show the title, which normally cannot be scripted to be shown, but using the magic of CSS-generated content, we can display the title info in an attractive and customizable way.

i belive the code hits a marker, not sure if that's what you have, but it should be able to work on anything with a title.

in my case, the title was on this (which could be transparent if needed):

```
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
          icon: {
              path: 0,
              scale: 3,
              fillColor: spot.color,
              strokeWeight: 8,
              strokeColor: spot.color,
              fillOpacity: 1,
              strokeOpacity: 0.333
          },
         title: "^ "+spot.name
    });
```